# Collection object is not callable error with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Following along the PyMongo [tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html) and am getting an error when calling the `insert_one` method on a collection.

```
In [1]: import pymongo

In [2]: from pymongo import MongoClient

In [3]: client = MongoClient()

In [4]: db = client.new_db

In [5]: db
Out[5]: Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'new_db')

In [6]: posts = db.posts

In [7]: posts.insert_one({'a':1})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2271c01f9a85> in <module>()
----> 1 posts.insert_one({'a':1})

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pymongo-2.8-py2.7-win32.egg\pymongo\collection.py in __call__(self, *a
rgs, **kwargs)
   1771                         "call the '%s' method on a 'Collection' object it is "
   1772                         "failing because no such method exists." %
-> 1773                         self.__name.split(".")[-1])

TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insert_one' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

There are a few posts online that discuss this error but all seem to be when the user calls a deprecated name.

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I would just like to add that this is an example of what is called here a "clear" example. Those monitoring would do well to follow the example.

Comment: This just happened to me as well. Thanks for posting =).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It is a clear question but the problem here seems to be that you are reading from the ["beta"](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html) release documentation but in all likelihood you actually at most have "pymongo" 2.8 installed rather than the "3.0b" referred to in the link you quote.

The [2.8 release tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/tutorial.html#inserting-a-document) points to the [`.insert()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.8/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert) method instead:

```
posts.insert({'a':1})
```

Since [`.insert_one()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) is only available in the 3.0b driver.

Either force the installation of the "beta" driver or live with a stable driver and the available methods.

This seems to be the fault of the current "search engine response" matching the "beta release" as "current".

Comment: @strimp099 Not your fault really. Feel for your pain. This is just a "by-product" of changes being issued around the recent MongoDB 3.0 release. Drivers are changing to make sure they keep up. Specifically this is all about using the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) with specific methods.

Comment: Well, I have pymongo 3.7 and still get the same error message. Using `insert` instead of `insert_one` does not help.

Answer (score 23):

The problem is that you are following the tutorial from the current release documentation but actually have PyMongo 2.8 installed.

The [`insert_one()`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) method is new in PyMongo 3.0 now backported in [PyMongo 2.9](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.9/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one). So clearly you will need to install PyMongo 2.9 or newer version in order to use the new API feature.

You can install or upgrade your driver using `pip` like.

```
python -m pip install -U pymongo
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when calling update on a collection. It's now:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient('localhost', 27017).my_db_name
db.my_collection_name.update_one( ... )
```

Answer (score -2):

I was facing the same problem too. When I tried upgrading my PyMongo distribution using the command,

```
pip install -U pymongo
```

I got the following error :

> error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo': Permission denied

Apparently, on my distro, the installer was not able to create a library in the **dist-packages** folder due to insufficient permission privileges. So, I solved the problem by granting it write permissions and re-installing the PyMongo driver:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/
sudo chmod 0777 dist-packages
pip install -U pymongo
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you should not change these permissions but use `sudo -H pip install -U pymongo` or `pip install --user -U pymongo`

Comment: You may also need to run pip as administrator in Windows if you installed it as administrator.