# bson.errors.InvalidDocument but types look correct

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, pymongo, python-3.4

In light of previous posts on the topic, where the dictionary is set up improperly or a data type is being used that PyMongo can't convert, I've expanded my logging to pick up the whole dictionary where the error occurs. Here's the full output at the relevant spot:

```
2015-03-19 02:03:32,255 ERROR quoteserver.updateeq :  Exception inserting into 'quotes': {'Quote_Time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 19, 16, 0), '_id': ObjectId('550a2e7480eb420629c2101a'), 'Vol': 1, 'Expiry': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 15, 0, 0), 'Bid': 11.25, 'Strike': 13.0, 'Opt_Symbol': 'GE160115C00013000', 'Ask': 12.9, 'Underlying': 'GE', 'Opt_Type': 'call', 'Last': 12.75, 'Open_Int': 51}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quoteserver.py", line 93, in updateeq
    _insertion_result = _quotes.insert_one(_entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 447, in insert_one
    return InsertOneResult(self._insert(document),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 411, in _insert
    gen(), check_keys, self.codec_options, client)
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: 1
```

The particularly weird part is that exactly the same code works on my Mac but then not (as here) on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14. Could the strings or something be encoded in a weird way that doesn't show up when just "printing" the dictionary? Or am I just blind and missing something more obvious?

Here is also a link to the line in the [source code](https://github.com/aisthesis/optbot/blob/ec2/db/quoteserver.py#L95) where it stops working. I'm running Mongo 3.0.1 and pymongo 3.0b0.

Comment: What MongoDB server version is the remote instance running? MonoDB 2.4.x? Also what pymongo version? It would appear to be a recent one given your use of `.insert_one()`

Comment: I wonder whether it might have to do with differences in Python 3 between string and byte stream. It would be kind of  a pain to `.encode()` each string in the dict, but to me the error message sounds like that kind of issue. And I notice that pymongo only recently added support for Python 3.

Comment: The likely case here is that MongoDB 2.4 does not understand the protocol being used for a [Bulk API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) method. That is what newly formed methods like `.insert_one()` are using "under the hood". Encoding should not be a problem, is if the data is not determined to be a `String` or any other strict type in the driver then it will just be submitted as `Binary`. MongoDB does not care in that way. But true, it is a "beta" driver implementation, and as such might just have some problems. Use at your own risk.

Comment: would you recommend backing up to a prior version of pymongo and/or MongoDB and/or Python 2 instead of 3? More exactly: What the latest release of each that's known to be reasonably stable?

Comment: Stable is still presently 2.8. There's a bit of a current problem that is leading people to 3.0.x documentation resulting is issues as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981718/collection-object-is-not-callable-error-with-pymongo/28982139#28982139)

Comment: Great, thanks. 2.8 doesn't support Python 3 yet, though, right?

Comment: Top of my head I'm really not sure. It is all documented so there is always a source to find those things out. I personally bleed tests on various VM setups ( or really linux containers ) all of the time with different configurations to app dependencies. It's a good way to trap problems like this. Test, Test and then Test again.