# TypeError: 'MongoClient' object is not callable

Tags: python, mongodb

I have this newbie problem in my python program which is given below
, I tried my best to solve it. but I can't solve it by my own, can you guys help me
here is my code.

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/')

db = client('Employee')

information = db.employeeinfo
records = {
    "fname": "Dhruvin",
    "lname": "Prajapati",
    "role": "Developer"
}
information.insert_one(records)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Collection object is not callable error with PyMongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981718/collection-object-is-not-callable-error-with-pymongo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error occurs when you try to call, with `()`, an object that is not callable. In python, a callable object can be a function or a class.

To access the DB from `MongoClient` object you should use it like `client['Employee']` or `client.Employee`

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/')

db = client.Employee

information = db.employeeinfo
records = {
    "fname": "Dhruvin",
    "lname": "Prajapati",
    "role": "Developer"
}
information.insert_one(records)
```

please find the document link for `MongoClient` here https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute `client` as if it was a function. To [access a database](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#getting-a-database), use either the subscription or dot notation:

```
db = client['Employee']
# alternatively: db = client.Employee
```