# Collection' object is not callable

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ansible

I am learning ansible on my local vagrant vm machine and I am setting up mongodb using ansible and I keep getting the error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'authenticate' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
fatal: [192.168.56.11]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 192.168.56.11 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640759955.2153473-3678-226245830655855/AnsiballZ_mongodb_user.py\", line 107, in <module>\r\n    _ansiballz_main()\r\n  File \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640759955.2153473-3678-226245830655855/AnsiballZ_mongodb_user.py\", line 99, in _ansiballz_main\r\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r\n  File \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1640759955.2153473-3678-226245830655855/AnsiballZ_mongodb_user.py\", line 47, in invoke_module\r\n  ...
```

The anisble playbook configuration:

```
# tasks file for mongodb
- include_vars: secrets.yml
- name: Installing mongodb
  apt:
   name: mongodb
   state: present
- name: Start and enable the engine
  service:
    name: mongodb
    state: started
    enabled: yes
- name: Configure Mongodb to accept outside connections
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/mongodb.conf
    regexp: '^#?bind_ip = 127.0.0.1'
    line: '#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1'
  notify:
     - restart mongodb
- name: Update Ubuntu
  apt:  update_cache=yes force_apt_get=yes cache_valid_time=3600
- name: Install Python pip
  apt:
    name: python3-pip
    state: present
- name: Install pymongo package
  pip:
    name: pymongo
    state: present
- name: Is authentication enabled?
  command: grep "^auth = true" /etc/mongodb.conf
  register: auth
  ignore_errors: yes
- name: Add an administrator to the db
  mongodb_user:
    database: admin
    name: root
    password: "{{ dbpass }}"
    roles: root
    state: present
  when: auth.rc == 1
- name: Enable authentication
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/mongodb.conf
    regexp: '^#?auth \= true'
    line: 'auth = true'
  notify:
    - restart mongodb
- name: Create the application user
  mongodb_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ dbpass }}"
    database: "{{ dbname }}"
    name: "{{ appdbuser }}"
    password: "{{ appdbpass }}"
    roles: dbOwner
    state: present
```

This part from my analysis of the error message is the issue:

```
- name: Create the application user
  mongodb_user:
    login_user: root
    login_password: "{{ dbpass }}"
    database: "{{ dbname }}"
    name: "{{ appdbuser }}"
    password: "{{ appdbpass }}"
    roles: dbOwner
    state: present
```

My anisble machine specifications are:

- Ubuntu vm:

  ```
   Linux ubuntu 5.4.0-80-generic #90-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 9 22:49:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
   Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
  ```
- Installed ansible version on Ubuntu vm:

  ```
   ansible [core 2.12.1]
      config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
      configured module search path = ['/home/vagrant/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
      ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
      ansible collection location = /home/vagrant/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
      executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
      python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) [GCC 9.4.0]
      jinja version = 2.10.1
      libyaml = True
  ```

Comment: Seems to be related to your Python package on that VM being out of date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28981718/collection-object-is-not-callable-error-with-pymongo

Comment: Could you have two instances of `pip` installed? Like one under `pip` and the other one under `pip3`. To confirm: `pip --version` and `pip3 --version`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I only have one version installed: ```pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```